# Why does the number appear to have been found if it has not yet been entered?

Tags: c++

I am coding a program in C ++, using lists, what I am doing is adding the entered numbers with the condition that the previous numbers are added to the number that has been searched. My program searches and displays the result, but the error is that if I search for data that has not yet been entered, it shows me the result. What should I do to validate that it has to be entered first?

Example: Enter: 1 2 3 4 5 6
Search: 5
Result: 1+2+3+4=10  because they are <5

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 
struct Nodo{ 
    int dato;
    Nodo *next;
};

Nodo *lista = NULL;

//list of functions
void menu();
void ingresarLista(Nodo *&, int);
void printList(Nodo *);
void searchList(Nodo *, int);
//funcion menu
void menu(){
    int option, dato;
    do{
        cout<<"MENU"<<endl;
        cout<<"1_Enter List of Whole Numbers"<<endl;
        cout<<"2_List sum before the entered number"<<endl;
        cout<<"s_Exit"<<endl;
        cout<<"Option"<<endl;
        cin>>option;
        //option with switch case
        switch(option){
            case 1: cout<<"Enter Number"<<endl;
                    cin>>dato;
                    ingresarLista(lista, dato);
                    cout<<endl;
                    system("pause");
                    break;
            case 2: cout<<"Search number"<<endl;
                    cin>>dato;
                    printList(lista);
                    cout<<endl;
                    searchList(lista, dato);
                    cout<<endl;
                    system("pause");
                    break;
        }
        system("cls");
    }while(option != 's');
}
//function menu
void ingresarLista(Nodo *&lista, int n){
    Nodo * nnodo = new Nodo();
    nnodo->dato = n;
    Nodo *aux1 = lista;
    Nodo *aux2;
    while((aux1 != NULL)&&(aux1->dato < n)){
        aux2 = aux1;
        aux1 = aux1->next;
    }
    if(lista == aux1){
        lista = nnodo;
    }
    else{
        aux2->next = nnodo;
    }
    nnodo->next = aux1;
    cout<<"Inserted"<<n<<"Successfully";
}
//print
void printList(Nodo *lista){
    Nodo *actual = new Nodo();
    actual = lista;
    while(actual != NULL){
        cout<<actual->dato<<">>";
        actual= actual->next;
    }
}
//sum and search number
void searchList(Nodo *lista, int n){
    bool band = false;// bandera
    int b=0;
    //se inicializa a 0 
    Nodo *actual = new Nodo();
    actual = lista;
    while(actual != NULL){
        if(actual->dato == n){
            band = true;
        }
        actual = actual->next;
        b=b+lista->dato;
        lista=lista->next;
}
    if(band == true){
        cout<<"The number " <<n<<" Exist"<<endl;
        cout<<"Sum "<<b<<" before the last node"<<endl;
        system("PAUSE");
    }
    else{
        cout<<"The number "<<n<<" does not exist"<<endl;
        cout<<"Can not be added "<<b<<endl;
    }
    
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    menu();//funcion menu
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never set your flag variable `band` to be true. If you change:

```c
        if(actual->dato == n){
            band = false;
        }
```

to

```c
        if(actual->dato == n){
            band = true;
        }
```

and also:

```c
    if(band == false){
        cout<<"The number " <<n<<" Exist"<<endl;
        cout<<"Sum "<<b<<" before the last node"<<endl;
        system("PAUSE");
    }
    else{
        cout<<"The number "<<n<<" does not exist"<<endl;
        cout<<"Can not be added "<<b<<endl;
    }
```

to

```c
    if(band == true){
        cout<<"The number " <<n<<" Exist"<<endl;
        cout<<"Sum "<<b<<" before the last node"<<endl;
        system("PAUSE");
    }
    else{
        cout<<"The number "<<n<<" does not exist"<<endl;
        cout<<"Can not be added "<<b<<endl;
    }
```

it should solve your problem.

With these changes `band` starts off as `false`, gets set to `true` only if a match is found and the message printed depends on the value of `band`.

In response to your comment, I missed this other bug. In the search routine the `while` condition needs to be changed from:

```c
while((actual != NULL)&&(actual->dato<n))
```

to:

```c
while(actual != NULL)
```

otherwise it will never find a match. I suspect you copied and pasted the condition from the insertion logic and forgot to remove the additional condition. (Both terms are needed in the insert function).

Comment: Thanks, I already made the change, but no previously entered number is recognized.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more info. It's not quite everything you want (based on the comment above), but it should get you close. Basically you need to not add the matched number to the total.